# Android: ListView's setEmptyView correct positioning

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i'm trying to provide a emptyView for a `ListView` and i also want to add it programmatically (or from a separate layout resource file) because i don't want to have it in my layout files. So far i managed to display it only when i add

```
        emptyList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ((ViewGroup)list.getParent()).addView(emptyList);
```

in my code, which is not very nice but seems to be nescessary. The problem is the positioning of the emptyView. If i have more than just my `ListView` in the whole layout, the emptyView is not positioned inside the `ListView`s display area. I guess thats by design though.

What would be the best way to position the view correctly? Could i achieve this wihtout much overhead in code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the empty view positioning in the layout is done 100% by the developer. Yes, that is by design, Android in general favours flexibility than easy of coding.

If you look in the [`AdapterView` source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/AdapterView.java) you'll see what I'm talking about, around line 737 you'll see this

```
mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and this

```
if (mEmptyView != null) mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

that means, all that the `ListView` do with the `emptyView` object you're passing is calling `setVisibility(boolean)` on it.

So, now that we know it's just a normal layout, with no special treatment it's easier to handle it. If you don't want to write on your layout again and again the same XML for empty view, you can (should) have a empty_view.xml with just the empty view and inside each of your XML with the list you position the empty_view.xml using the `<include>` tag. Like this: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html and on the code you simply call:

```
listview.setEmptyView(root.findViewById(R.id.empty_view));
```

or you can do it by code still... but that will involve setting layout params for the "parent" to proper organise it.

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that was what i suspected. But also using an `include` would mean i (at least sometimes, LiniearLayout i.e.) i would have to embed the `ListView` in an extra `RelativeLayout`. I don't like that. I was hoping the adapter would be somehow capable of populating the "inner view" as it does with its items. Maybe i'll try to achieve something with a custom adapter...

Comment: nope. The ListView and the View (that is set as Empty view) is a separate separate views. If you're for example using a PullToRefreshLayout, you can include inside it, as the PullToRefresh already extends FrameLayout. As you can see the `getParent` will give you back a layout (if I'm not mistake it's a FrameLayout android.R.id.content, which is the base of the Activity), you can setup all the layout parameters via Java, but it's just more complex/annoying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView ... />

    <include
      android:id="@+id/empty_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />        
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you put the `empty view` in a `RelativeLayout` with your `ListView` and being created after the `ListView` it will cover the `ListView` when you set it `visible`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, even though it keeps out complex layout definition it would still need some adjustment. So for me that is unfortunately no ideal solution, i was hoping to keep it out at all.